# How do I get multiple html files to reference a single .js file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website for a client.  It occurred to me that I might have to create similar websites in the future, so I would like to create a template website that allows me to change specific parts of the website to make the site fit to the particular client.  I want to go to one file where I can change the contact information (name, phone number, email, ect) and these changes will update across all the html files.

In addition I want to set up the template so that I can dynamically populate links in navbars and footers.  Ultimately this will be a 12 to 15 page website, I only want to update the data for the navbar/footer in one file so that the rest of the 12 to 15 pages with navbars/footers will dynamically populate.

Here is my file tree.  Currently there is no css, only html.

- main directory

  - css folder

    - main.css
    - main.css.map
    - main.scss
  - Javascript Folder

    - index.js
  - about.html
  - contact.html
  - index.html

---

Below is index.js file.  Currently, this works for index.html, meaning that contact information in the footer is correctly populated, and the links in the navbar element are correctly populated.  This file is not populating the links in contact.html & about.html.  Herein lies my problem.  Is there a way to use this one index.js file to update the links in  elelments in contact.html and about.html?

```
let yourName = document.querySelector('#yourName');
let NMLS = document.querySelector('#NMLS');
let address1 = document.querySelector('#address1')
let address2 = document.querySelector('#address2')
let cityState = document.querySelector('#cityState')
let phone = document.querySelector('#phone')
let email = document.querySelector('#email')
let hours = document.querySelector('#hours')

let homeLink = document.getElementById('homeLink')
let aboutLink = document.getElementById("aboutLink");
let contactLink = document.getElementById('contactLink')

// Change this data depending on client

let firstName = "John"
let lastName = "Doe"
let yourNMLS = "359846"
let yourAddress1 = "1235 4th Street"
let yourAddress2 = ""
let yourCity = "San Diego"
let yourState = "CA"
let yourZip = "96586"
let yourLocalCity = "Escondido"
let yourPhone = "619-213-2589"
let yourEmail = "youremail@gmail.com"
let daysOpen = "Daily"
let hoursOpen = "8:00AM - 5:00PM"

// data for links in navbar
let yourAboutLink = "about.html"
let yourHomeLink = "index.html"
let yourContactLink = "contact.html"

// leave this alone

yourName.innerHTML = `${firstName} ${lastName}`
NMLS.innerHTML = `NMLS: ${yourNMLS}`
address1.innerHTML = `${yourAddress1}`
address2.innerHTML = `${yourAddress2}`
cityState.innerHTML = `${yourCity}, ${yourState} ${yourZip}`
email.innerHTML = `${yourEmail}`
phone.innerHTML =`${yourPhone}`
hours.innerHTML = `${daysOpen}: ${hoursOpen}`
homeLink.href = `${yourHomeLink}`
aboutLink.href = `${yourAboutLink}`
contactLink.href = `${yourContactLink}`
```

Below is index.html file.  The relevant sections are the nav element in header element, and the ul and li elements in the footer elements

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>Loan officer website template</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Header Start -->
  <div class="hero-wrapper">
    <header>
      <a href="#" class="logo">Company Logo</a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a id="homeLink" href="#">home</a></li>
          <li><a id="aboutLink" href="#">about</a></li>
          <li><a id="contactLink" href="#">contact</a></li>
          <li><a id ="applyNowLink" href="#">Apply Now</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="hero-content">
      <h1>Your Name Home Loans</h1>
      <p class="subtitle">Your Local Mortgage Experts</p>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- Qiuck features start -->
  <div class="quick-features">
    <div class="quick-features-content">
      <h1>Your "Name of city" Mortgage Experts</h1>
      <p class="subtitle">Welcome to your hometown Escondido mortgage professionals</p>
    </div>
    <div class="features-cards-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="#" alt="house icon">
          <h2>Purchase Loans</h2>
          <p>Get Pre-Qualified</p>
          <p>Mortgage Process</p>
          <p>Types of Mortgage</p>
          <p>Glossary of Terms</p>
          <p>Understanding Your Credit</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="#" alt="hourglass icon">
          <h2>Refinancing</h2>
          <p>Refinancing Facts</p>
          <p>Types of Mortgages</p>
          <p>Our Blogess</p>
          <p>Process of a Mortgage</p>
          <p>Understanding Your Credit</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="#" alt="pencil and pad icon">
          <h2>Popular Mortgage Programs</h2>
          <p>FHA</p>
          <p>Conventional</p>
          <p>203(K)</p>
          <p>VA</p>
          <p>View All Programs</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Testimonials start -->
<div class="testimonials-wrapper">
  <div class="testimonials-content-wrapper">
    <h1>What our clients say</h1>
    <hr>
    <ul class="testimonials">
      <li>
        <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto adipisci inventore quam possimus. Reprehenderit odit harum aut ut omnis libero neque voluptatibus nulla sequi ea tenetur consequuntur nam molestias, cupiditate praesentium! Mollitia ab totam, qui recusandae accusantium animi accusamus molestias, id reprehenderit debitis a consequuntur, vel praesentium hic veniam quam provident! Facere molestias aliquid molestiae. Labore consequatur commodi ex a?</blockquote>
        <cite>John Doe</cite>
      </li>
      <li>
        <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto adipisci inventore quam possimus. Reprehenderit odit harum aut ut omnis libero neque voluptatibus nulla sequi ea tenetur consequuntur nam molestias, cupiditate praesentium! Mollitia ab totam, qui recusandae accusantium animi accusamus molestias, id reprehenderit debitis a consequuntur, vel praesentium hic veniam quam provident! Facere molestias aliquid molestiae. Labore consequatur commodi ex a?</blockquote>
        <cite>Jane Doe</cite>
      </li>
      <li>
        <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto adipisci inventore quam possimus. Reprehenderit odit harum aut ut omnis libero neque voluptatibus nulla sequi ea tenetur consequuntur nam molestias, cupiditate praesentium! Mollitia ab totam, qui recusandae accusantium animi accusamus molestias, id reprehenderit debitis a consequuntur, vel praesentium hic veniam quam provident! Facere molestias aliquid molestiae. Labore consequatur commodi ex a?</blockquote>
        <cite>Mark Smith</cite>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- blog start -->
<div class="blog-wrapper">
  <h1>Blog</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="blog-content-wrapper">
    <ul class="blog-content">
      <li>
        <img src="#" alt="blog image">
        <h4>Title of blog entry</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, dolore illo, voluptas dolor explicabo, iusto magnam dolorum accusamus et quisquam voluptatem maxime quasi ullam consequuntur.
        </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="#" alt="blog image">
        <h4>Title of blog entry 2</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, dolore illo, voluptas dolor explicabo, iusto magnam dolorum accusamus et quisquam voluptatem maxime quasi ullam consequuntur.
        </p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="#" alt="blog image">
        <h4>Title of blog entry 3</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, dolore illo, voluptas dolor explicabo, iusto magnam dolorum accusamus et quisquam voluptatem maxime quasi ullam consequuntur.
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Call to action -->
<div class="call-to-action-wrapper">
  <h1>Questions?</h1>
  <button>Contact Us</button>
</div>
<!-- footer -->
<footer>
  <div class="contact-info-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h2>Call Us</h2>
        <p id="phone"></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>email</h2>
        <p id="email"></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>Open Hours (PST)</h2>
        <p id="hours"></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="nmls-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h2>Contact</h2>
        <p id="yourName"></p>
        <p id="NMLS"></p>
        <p id="address1"></p>
        <p id="address2"></p>
        <p id="cityState"></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="#" alt="equal housing logo">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<hr>
<div class="disclaimer-wrapper">
  <p>Disclaimer</p>
  <p>All information is deemed reliable but not guaranteed. All properties are subject to prior sale, charge or withdrawal. Neither listing broker(s) or information provider(s) shall be responsible for any typographical errors, misinformation, misprints and shall be held totally harmless. Listing(s) information is provided for consumers personal, non-commercial use and may not be used for any purpose other than to identify prospective properties consumers may be interested in purchasing.</p>

  <p>Copyright © 2020, ODL Websites. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript"src="./javascript/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is contact.html file.  Again, my index.js is not working with this file, meaning the links in nav element are not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Contact Page</h1>

  <header>
    <a href="#" class="logo">Company Logo</a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="homeLink" href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a id="aboutLink" href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a id="contactLink" href="#">contact</a></li>
        <li><a id ="applyNowLink" href="#">Apply Now</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>


  <script type="text/javascript"src="./javascript/index.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Finally my about.html file.  Again, index.js is not working with this file, meaning the links in nav are not updating.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>About Page</h1>

  <header>
    <a href="#" class="logo">Company Logo</a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="homeLink" href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a id="aboutLink" href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a id="contactLink" href="#">contact</a></li>
        <li><a id ="applyNowLink" href="#">Apply Now</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <script type="text/javascript"src="./javascript/index.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there's no `#yourName` element on the second and third files, when you do `yourName.innerHTML = '${firstName} ${lastName}';` it is probably throwing an error (check your console).

To avoid that first check if the element exists:

```
if (yourName) yourName.innerHTML = '${firstName} ${lastName}';
if (NMLS) NMLS.innerHTML = `NMLS: ${yourNMLS}`
...
```